# Install 3 Kubernetes Master and 3 nodes

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, devops, haproxy, kubernetes-pod

I was going through this tutorial http://dockerlabs.collabnix.com/kubernetes/beginners/Install-and-configure-a-multi-master-Kubernetes-cluster-with-kubeadm.html
but facing issue while running HAPROXY even few things are not clear.
I can install 1 Master and n number of nodes but facing challenge for  3 master 3 nodes.
Can some one help me ?

Comment: Clarify your use-case. Is the 3 Master nodes mainly for high availability?

Comment: Yes i want for high availability

Comment: Are you by accident on AWS? I would consider checking kops on github. They have different install scenarios in their docs

Comment: Yes I'm using ec2 machine on aws

Answer (score 1):

For High Availability K8s Control Plane Implementation, you can refer to this documentation: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/highly-available-master/

If you are in the cloud, There are many libraries that can help you implement it using only a setting toggle.

- Multi-Cloud : [Kops](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops)
- AWS Only: [AWS EKS](https://aws.amazon.com/eks/features/) (Manage Services, highly available by default)

[image]